# "on leave from" vs. "on leave on"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> **A**: I will be on leave from 3rd, 4th October.
>   **B**: I will be on leave on 3rd, 4th October

Which one is correct?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Nice wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong. The correct sentences are:

> **I will be on leave on the 3rd and 4th  of October**.
>
> **I will be on leave on October 3rd and 4th.**

Answer (score 0):

The preposition ***from*** in this adverbial clause must be followed by a ***single*** date (the date when a multiple-day timespan ***starts***). If you also want to specify the ***end*** date of the range (which is syntactically optional), this must be preceded by the preposition ***to***. But it's relatively "unusual" to specify a span of just two consecutive dates as ***from*** [StartDate] **to** [EndDate] - in that situation we'd normally just "list" the two dates as ***on*** [Date1] **and** [Date2].

<sub>Transcribed from a comment by FumbleFingers, who should leave more answers and less long comments.</sub>